# Yarn-site.xml missing

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to install hadoop-2.2.0. I have used following command

1. `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/hadoop`
2. `sudo cp hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz /usr/lib/hadoop     cd /usr/lib/hadoop`
3. `sudo tar xzvf hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz`

After this i have to change files in HADOOP.
The first problem is there is no *"***etc***"* folder in "**/usr/local/hadoop/**".
Second is that i found files like hdfs-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml etc in "***config***" folder inside hadoop. But "***Yarn-site.xml***" is not missing. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you following any documentation? Why do you think there should be an `etc` folder there? Also, it will be probably much easier if you use a pre-packaged distribution.

Comment: i am not following a particular documentation. As for **etc**  i have seen it on many sites about hadoop installation. The main problem is how come there are all the files available like hdfs-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml but not YARN-SITE.xml?

Comment: No idea. But if you're not following any documentation, definitely do so. And I really, really recommend you use a pre-packaged distribution such as those from Cloudera or Hortonworks.

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your hadoop cluster correctly. Depends on the version of Hadoop you can find the configuration file under hadoop/etc/hadoop or under hadoop/conf.

Download hadoop 2.4. It's better [follow this link](http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/) to do so, it may help you setting up your cluster.

```
$ cd ~
$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.4.0/hadoop2.4.0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf hadoop-2.4.0.tar.gz
$ mv hadoop-2.4.0 hadoop
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'm doing my best :) and trying to help